# How can i kill x server and be put into a command prompt?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, command-line

Is there a way to kil xserver and put me into a command prompt or something? (Ubuntu 11.10)

Normally killing xserver with `sudo stop lightgdm` puts me into a BIOS-esque black screen.

Where can I type but commands cannot be issued?

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a Virtual terminal. There are several more, from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>. <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> are usually used for running your X server and some messages.

Note that you need to login to those terminals first, before you can use them.

Comment: perfect. how do i log in as root through this? and more importantly, how do i go about exiting the prompt (thank gawd for fast reboots)?

Comment: Just like you usually login as root. Either you have a root password set, so you login as user root and use the root password. Or you just login with your usual credentials and run `sudo su` to get a root shell. You can exit from the prompt using `exit`. (Note that you need to exit twice, if you use `su`: once out of the root shell and then out of your user shell.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>? Then. you should be able to return to X with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>